# error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/httpd/logs: cpio: rename

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, epel

I'm working on an old server of mine. I'm trying to run `yum update` and there seems to be an issue.

So far, I've tried setting that log directory to 777 and same with the 2 log files within it.

That didn't help. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * extras: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * updates: centos.quelquesmots.fr
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-30.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-69.el6.centos will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch                                          Version                                                      Repository                                   Size
===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 httpd                                        x86_64                                        2.2.15-69.el6.centos                                         base                                        836 k

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 836 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                               | 836 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/2 
Error unpacking rpm package httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64
warning: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf created as /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/httpd/logs: cpio: rename
httpd-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : httpd-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/2 
  Verifying  : httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       2/2 

Failed:
  httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-30.el6.centos                                                                  httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-69.el6.centos                                                                 

Complete!
```

Trying another command:

```
# yum install google-chrome-stable
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * extras: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * updates: centos.quelquesmots.fr
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:71.0.3578.98-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liberation-fonts for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatspi.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libatspi.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: liberation-fonts
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
httpd-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-tools = ('0', '2.2.15', '30.el6.centos')
httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd = ('0', '2.2.15', '69.el6.centos')
```

Comment: You've posted two separate, unrelated problems here. That you can't install Google Chrome has absolutely nothing to do with being unable to update httpd. (It requires CentOS 7 and doesn't work at all (anymore) on 6.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton They are not unrelated. The errors both revolve around httpd updates.

Comment: Have you try to change by hand the repo host? FOr me it seems like problematic files in repo

Comment: Um, what? The error you got about Google Chrome is still completely unrelated to installing httpd. I don't understand why you are trying to claim that it is.

Comment: @RomeoNinov again, it’s an old server so i don’t know what i did 5 years ago

Comment: Try to change the repo now. ANd for me this is more UNIX&Linux question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/